# How to load image from url?

Tags: android

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to load image from url](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4321224/how-to-load-image-from-url)

I want to know how to load image from URL and save in local database.

Pls help me

Thanks
Monali

Comment: please specify your answer - what exactly do you want to do, what have you tried to so far, etc..

Answer (score 2):

-You might find some help in loading the image from a URL in:

[How to load an ImageView by URL in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2471935/how-to-load-an-imageview-by-url-in-android)

-As for saving it, this may be useful:

[Save bitmap to location](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/649154/android-bitmap-save-to-location)

Answer (score 1):

To do this, you should use the MediaStore API

```
String yourImageFilename= String.valueOf(System.currentTimeMillis()); //using this for simplicity

ContentValues cValues = new ContentValues();   
cValues.put(Images.Media.TITLE, yourImageFilename);
cValues.put(Images.Media.DATE_ADDED, System.currentTimeMillis()); 
cValues.put(Images.Media.MIME_TYPE, "image/jpeg"); //your image type here, jpg for sample

Uri uri = context.getContentResolver().insert(Images.Media.INTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, values);

try {

  OutputStream outStream = context.getContentResolver().openOutputStream(uri);
  Url imageResource = new Url("your url string");
  Bitmap mBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(imageResource.openStream());

  mBitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 90, outStream); //if you want to compress the jpg

  outStream.flush();
  outStream.close();

} catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
  e.printStackTrace();
} catch (IOException e) {
  e.printStackTrace();
}
```

I am assuming you mean in the local database(viewable by the gallery, if not then please edit your question to be more specific).